# Which framework should i use to create web Project in Python?

Tags: python, frameworks

### Web App in python which use speech input and report to view and download.

Project mainly include, speech input and report view and download in pdf, doc and sheet. and little information of profile and progress report to store in database.
Also recommend, which Software should to use.
Currenty using visual studio and Sql Server.

Comment: Use the software that you are most familiar with.  Familiarity allows you to make better choices; if you think a framework might be suitable, but you know nothing about it, then study it a bit.  This will allow you to make better decisions.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, item 4.

Answer (score 0):

The two most popular web frameworks for Python are Django and Flask. Flask tends to be less opinionated about things like database structure, so I would read into both to figure out which one will better fit your needs. In my opinion, unless you need all of the features Django offers out of the box, use Flask with whatever other plugins/frameworks best suit your needs.